# What is the term for this operation on vectors?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let's say I have a vector of integers such as

$$ \langle1,23,3\rangle \\
\langle41,5,16\rangle \\
 \langle3,5,7\rangle \\
 \langle10,13,31\rangle $$

and I wish to create a new vector whose entries are all entries in the $i$th position of the above vectors. For example, I wish to create a vector whose entries are all entries in the 3rd position of the above vectors as follows:

$$ \langle3,16,7,31\rangle $$

Is there a name/term for such a vector?

Thanks

Comment: Just worth noting, nothing’s bout this specifically requires integers, and there is probably not a name specifically for integers.

Answer (score 0):

Try to compute
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 23 & 3 \\
41 & 5 & 16 \\
3 & 5 & 7 \\
10 & 13 & 31
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ 0 \\ 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Very simple "column indexing" (I'm sure there's a standard name for this). Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Since you have also put the tag of matrices, what you are doing is a matrix operation. Consider the matrix which is the rows of the vectors you have

$$M = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 23 & 3 \\ 41&5&16\\3&5&7\\10&13&31\end{bmatrix}$$

Now, if you want to extract the $i^{th}$ element, you need only multiply this matrix with the vector $e_i = <0,0,0..,1,...0,0,0>$ (1 in the ith place, rest 0)